# Effective way to use must and must_not in a single search phrase?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch and lookig currently into must and must_not type of search criteria.
I have the following query DSL:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/employee/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "age": "40" } }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        { "match": { "state": "ID" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Now my question is , is there any way i can optimize the above query?
Like, if i have to search for multiple must and must_not criteria, the query would become very large and difficult to manage. Is there any way i can combine both must and must_not under a single search phrase?

Comment: Are you talking about manageability of the query or performance when you talk about "is there any way i can optimize the above query?" If you are interested in performance, be sure to read up on query and filter context: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you could use "should" to put several matches inside a "bool" statement (not sure why exactly it does not work with directly one "bool" statement):

**Edit** Actually to have several matches, without a too complex request, what is below should work normally:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool":{
          "must": [
            {"match":{"age":"40"}},
            {"match":{"name": "John"}}
          ]
          , "must_not": [
                {"match":{"age":"40"}},
            {"match":{"name": "John"}}
          ]
        }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, `must` and `must_not` cannot be combined

Comment: Edited the query after some research on it, now to be fair in my experience, queries can tend to get rather complicated (in the 100th of lines ) with all the power DSL queries offer

Comment: Proper indentation goes a long way. I'd highly recommend Console (part of Kibana) since it provides syntax highlighting, auto completion, indentation,...

Comment: True, though my formatting from Sense to SO got a little bit whacked on its face...